# Making entire table row clickable using React Router Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm fairly new to React.
I have a Component named ***Content***, that serves as a container for 2 other components called **List** and **Profile**.

```
class Content extends Component{
  <HashRouter>
    <Route exact path="/list">
       <List *props are entered here*/>
     </Route>
     <Route exact path="/profile">
        <Profile foo = {this.foo} *props are entered here*/>
     </Route>
  </HashRouter>
}
```

Inside **List**, I have a table of users that I mapped out from the state. When I click on the link, function **foo** gets the user id and passes it on to **Profile**, the **List** component will be replaced with the **Profile** component, displaying the selected user profile

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr >
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Link to profile</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  {this.state.users.map((user, index) =>
   <tr key={index}>
     <td>{user.name}</td>
     <td><Link to="/profile" onClick={() => this.props.foo(user.id)}</Link></td>
   </tr>
   )}
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Now clicking on the link inside the **`<td>`** obviously works, but I want to make the entire row act like a clickable **`<Link>`**

I tried binding an **onClick** function to `<tr>` but I don't know how to make it act like a `<Link>` where it replaces the component to **Profile**

**EDIT:** I managed to make it work using withRouter as per Jacob Smit's comment

1. I included withRouter from react-router-dom

   `export default withRouter(List)`
2. Added an onClick function in `<tr>` and a data-value attribute

   `<tr key={index} onClick={this.clickRow} data-value{user.id}>`
3. in the clickRow() function

   `this.props.foo(event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-value"); this.props.history.push("/profile")`

I didn't pass the `user.id` in `clickRow` because for some odd reason, it automatically triggers it when the page is loaded so I tried to remove it. Haven't investigated yet but will work this solution for now.

Comment: since you are using class components you can use `withRouter` to push `history` onto your component through props. you can then use `history.push(/* URL HERE */)` to make the application route. If you use any function components you can use the hook `useHistory` instead of the `withRouter` HOC.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. put an onClick event on

   `<tr key={index} onClick={this.handleOnClick(user.id)}>`
2. in handleOnClick, use Redirect to link to another page, also you may need to pass props to Redirect.

```js
handleOnClick = (userid) => {
      return <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: "/profile",
        foo: userid
        
      }}
    />
    }
```

Comment: It is not possible to use keyboard to navigate this.